# swift sort for multi criteria

Tags: swift, sorting

My sorting requirement have some special condition.

```swift
class Man {
    var id: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
    var childIds: [Man]()
    var parent: Man?
}
```

In fact the logic is simple.
If the object have no child/parent, it follow ascending name. But if the object have child, the child must below him.
Below is the sample expected output, the name with > means it is a child, and the above name is parent. I tried several ways, but still unable to set specific order for child/parent relation.

Andy

Bob

>Alex

Cindy

>Ben

Comment: We do not know what your data is, so your sorted example is meaningless.

Comment: And a child can also have children?

Comment: Can multiple parents have the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### What should you have for your model?

```
import Foundation

class Person: CustomStringConvertible {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let childrenIDs: [Int]
    let parent: Person?
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, childrenIDs: [Int] = [], parent: Person? = nil) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.childrenIDs = childrenIDs
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    var description: String {
        "<id: \(id), name: \(name)>"
    }
    
    var sortingName: String {
        "\(parent?.name ?? "")\(name)"
    }
}
```

##### How can you sort using it?

```
let cindy = Person(id: 4, name: "Cindy", childrenIDs: [5], parent: nil)
let ben = Person(id: 5, name: "Ben", childrenIDs: [], parent: cindy)
let andy = Person(id: 1, name: "Andy")
let bob = Person(id: 2, name: "Bob", childrenIDs: [3], parent: nil)
let alex = Person(id: 3, name: "Alex", childrenIDs: [], parent: bob)

let persons: [Person] = [ben, cindy, andy, alex, bob]
let sortedPersons = persons.sorted(by: { p1, p2 in
    p1.sortingName.compare(p2.sortingName) == .orderedAscending
})
print(sortedPersons)
```

##### Output

```
[
  <id: 1, name: Andy>,
  <id: 2, name: Bob>,
  <id: 3, name: Alex>,
  <id: 4, name: Cindy>,
  <id: 5, name: Ben>
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Never thought i can create another variable to resolve the child and parent relation.